# No command line prompt in Mac OSX Terminal.app

Tags: bash, mac, terminal

I've lost my bash command line prompt in Mac OSX (10.11), and I don't know where to start looking to fix it.

The issue started when I changed the "Shell opens with..." preference from "Default" to "Command (complete path)", specifying `/usr/local/bin/bash`.  When I restarted Terminal.app after making that change, the window appeared but I had no command line prompt:

[image: No prompt]

Any commands entered are ignored.

After that, I reset the "Shell opens with..." preference to "Default," and restarted Terminal.app again, but the problem persists.

Where do I go from here to get my terminal back?

### UPDATE

After multiple system restarts, this problem resolved itself.

### EDIT:

Here's a screenshot of my Terminal settings as of right now:

[image: Terminal settings]

Comment: open your ~/.bashrc in a text editor and see where it might be getting stuck. Does Terminal launch a login shell or no?

Comment: While you're editing ~/.bashrc, add `set -x` at the top to see what it's doing. No guarantees that the problem is in that file but if it is you'll see where you're getting stuck.

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for the idea.  however, 1. I did not alter my `.bash_profile` at all, and it's been working fine 2. I tried adding `echo hi` as the first line of the `.bash_profile`, and nothing is output.  does that give you any other clues?

Comment: Check the settings for Terminal: if it is not set to use a login shell, it won't look at .bash_profile. I was suggesting .bashrc.

Comment: @glennjackman See my update for a screenshot of my current terminal settings.  Mac's don't use `.bashrc`

Comment: Just in case, I created a `.bashrc` with `set -x` at the top, but restarting Terminal.app after doing that didn't produce any additional output.

Comment: I don't see "/usr/local/bin/bash" there. It's a default login shell. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files and read which files are processed for an interactive login shell.

Comment: @glennjackman Correct.  In my OP I described that I put the setting back to its original working state -- the default login shell.  This is the crux of my question.  I made a change to Terminal settings, something bad happened.  I reverted the change.  The bad thing persists.  I don't see how this is possible, but it is.  Again, I have not changed any of my startup files -- only the Terminal.app settings.  I want to know how I debug what has happened.

Comment: As a first step at diagnosis I'd try opening a shell and then running `/usr/local/bin/bash`. How was it installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple system restarts, this problem resolved itself.